# Cursor won't change when setting it via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor

Hi I wrote a little script where every time state 1 is triggered the cursor changes to a pointer, and when state 2 is triggered it changes to a crosshair.
Both states get triggered correctly and everything runs fine, except every time I am in state 1 only one of the divs which I want the cursor to change for show the right cursor.
In state 2 everthing works like it should.

HTML

```
<div id='first'></div>
<div id='second'></div>
```

JS

```
function state1 (){
$('#first').css({'cursor':'pointer'});
$('#second').css({'cursor':'pointer'});
};

function state2 (){
$('#first').css({'cursor':'crosshair'});
$('#second').css({'cursor':'crosshair'});
};
```

Comment: Show the full CSS which is set besides what you set programmatically. Also, when you inspect your `div`s using runtime DOM inspection tools, can you see the styles being set?

Comment: I would combine your two lines, e.g. `$('#first, #second').css({'cursor':'pointer'});`. This will improve your code's efficiency.

Comment: ...and as a second hint, you can just comma separate your selectors to match both in one go. I.e. `$('#first, #second')` to avoid repeating the same code twice.

Comment: The code as given works fine http://jsfiddle.net/VkSAM/ marking as unanswerable

Answer (score 0):

You don't execute function state1 properly in the code